# Break Haskell function down into subtasks without additional list traversals

Tags: haskell

So, I’m having a lot of trouble writing a program to make a covariance matrix from several large integer vectors, stored in separate files. I started by writing

```
mean xs = realToFrac (sum xs) / realToFrac (length xs)
cov xs ys = mean (zipWith (*) xs ys) - mean xs * mean ys
covmat vectors = [cov xs ys | ys <- vectors, xs <- vectors]
```

which worked for small input, but you can see how inefficient even just “mean” is. It keeps all the xs in memory when doing the sum, because they're going to be used by "length". That’s fixable, as so:

```
mean xs = realToFrac thisSum / realToFrac thisLength
    where (thisSum, thisLength) = foldl' (\(s,l) y-> (s+y,l+1)) (0,0) xs
```

but then I run into the same problem with “cov”. When I rewrote "cov" in this style, it didn't end up using my "mean" function. And I still have one level to go up when I write the "covmat" function, which will become extremely complicated.

So, I have two goals, which seem to be in conflict:

- Traverse each list once, without keeping it in memory
- Break down "covmat" into simpler, meaningful functions, specifically "cov" and "mean"

I don't see any way to unify these two goals with what I know of Haskell. But conceptually it seems simple: all of these functions need to "listen" to the values of the same few lists as they come in. Is there any way in Haskell to organize it like this? If this requires a different data structure or an additional library, I'm open to that.

Comment: This problem has been studied quite a lot.  See [this](http://squing.blogspot.com/2008/11/beautiful-folding.html) and [this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/folds) (and the links in the package description)

Comment: I like Gabriel's version of beautiful folds more: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6a5Ti0r8Q2s) and [library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl). The video is really clear and understandable. Not sure about Kmett's libraries... Also didn't find good tutorials about `folds` :(

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance#Covariance for a numerically stable online algorithm for calculating the covariance (use online_covariance).

Comment: I followed the squing blog post linked by @liqui to [attempt a solution](https://gist.github.com/user54038/d77e9daa3a2310e51e3fe866263273b7). The input is a tab-delimited matrix, we calculate the covariance matrix of the columns. The output is correct, but the memory usage is not constant. Maybe because I had to define a combinator allFolds, which combines all the folds in a list. I think I’m missing a required bang somewhere. It's very cool that you can write in this style but I need to learn to get the memory usage right. I'll be checking out the libraries linked by luqui and Shersh.

Comment: Link to my code was broken, [here's the correct one](https://gist.github.com/user54038/c20c85de4171705d860827339ef9d042)

Comment: Are you more interested in learning haskell or in calculating a covariance matrix efficiently?

Comment: I'm interested in learning to use Haskell to write tasks such as this one in a particular style, as specified in my question. Efficiency was one of the two goals in my bullet list. Thanks for the Wikipedia link, and that's probably the algorithm I'm actually going to use for now, but I'm still looking for an efficient solution that partitions the tasks into small, meaningful functions.

Comment: OK, I've [reimplemented with Gabriel's library](https://gist.github.com/user54038/81ed43ee489594ce9097fbe649b51f54), which was linked by @Shersh. It's pretty readable, broken down the way I wanted, and running in constant memory. I suspect the "allFolds" combinator I wrote is reinventing some wheel or another, and I'd like to learn to do it with stuff built-in to the library. But I'm very happy with this, and consider this question to be answered in the comments.

Answer (score 5):

So, I did some digging around, and I came up with the following.

EDIT: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/jhenahan/e90db4bcca6fcdb832522671a6c53399) for people who'd prefer that to the SO formatting.

First, a few implementations of mean

```
module Means where

import Data.List
import Control.Applicative

mean :: (Fractional a1, Real a, Foldable t) => t a -> a1
mean xs = realToFrac (sum xs) / realToFrac (length xs)

mean' :: (Foldable f, Fractional a) => f a -> a
mean' = liftA2 (/) sum (fromIntegral . length)

data Pair = Pair {-# UNPACK #-}!Int {-# UNPACK #-}!Double 

mean'' :: [Double] -> Double
mean'' xs = s / fromIntegral n
  where
    Pair n s = foldl' k (Pair 0 0) xs
    k (Pair n s) x = Pair (n+1) (s+x)
```

The last one uses an explicit strict pair constructor. IIRC, `(,)` is lazy, so this should give us better performance characteristics.

```
module Covariance where

import Means

covariance :: (Fractional a, Real a1) => [a1] -> [a1] -> a
covariance xs ys = mean (zipWith (*) xs ys) - mean xs * mean ys

covariance' :: Fractional a => [a] -> [a] -> a
covariance' xs ys = mean' (zipWith (*) xs ys) - mean' xs * mean' ys

covariance'' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance'' xs ys = mean'' (zipWith (*) xs ys) - mean'' xs * mean'' ys

covariance''' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance''' xs ys =
    let mx = mean'' xs
        my = mean'' ys
    in
    sum (zipWith (\x y -> (x - mx) * (y - my)) xs ys) / fromIntegral (length xs)
```

I tried a few versions of your `cov` using each of the different mean options, then one uglier "performance" version.

I threw together a simple `Main` with some hardcoded lists for testing.

```
module Main where

import Means
import Covariance

v1 = [1000000..2000000]

v2 = [2000000..3000000]

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- let cov = covariance v1 v2
  -- let cov = covariance' v1 v2
  -- let cov = covariance'' v1 v2
  let cov = covariance''' v1 v2
  print cov
```

Compiling with `-rtsopts` and running with `+RTS -s`, I got the following allocation information.

`covariance`:

```
8.33335e10
     531,816,984 bytes allocated in the heap
     890,566,720 bytes copied during GC
     148,609,912 bytes maximum residency (11 sample(s))
      15,649,528 bytes maximum slop
             374 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       981 colls,     0 par    0.385s   0.389s     0.0004s    0.0012s
  Gen  1        11 colls,     0 par    0.445s   0.584s     0.0531s    0.2084s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.194s  (  0.168s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.830s  (  0.973s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.029s elapsed)
module Main where
  Total   time    1.027s  (  1.172s elapsed)

  %GC     time      80.9%  (83.0% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    2,741,140,975 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  19.1% of total user, 16.8% of total elapsed
```

`covariance'`:

```
8.333350000320508e10
     723,822,456 bytes allocated in the heap
     891,626,240 bytes copied during GC
     185,629,664 bytes maximum residency (11 sample(s))
       3,693,296 bytes maximum slop
             435 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0      1372 colls,     0 par    0.388s   0.392s     0.0003s    0.0010s
  Gen  1        11 colls,     0 par    0.388s   0.551s     0.0501s    0.1961s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.227s  (  0.202s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.777s  (  0.943s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.029s elapsed)
  Total   time    1.006s  (  1.176s elapsed)

  %GC     time      77.2%  (80.2% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,195,430,190 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  22.8% of total user, 19.6% of total elapsed
```

`covariance''`:

```
8.333350000320508e10
     456,108,392 bytes allocated in the heap
     394,432,096 bytes copied during GC
      79,295,648 bytes maximum residency (15 sample(s))
      21,161,776 bytes maximum slop
             201 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       861 colls,     0 par    0.085s   0.089s     0.0001s    0.0005s
  Gen  1        15 colls,     0 par    0.196s   0.274s     0.0182s    0.0681s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.124s  (  0.106s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.282s  (  0.362s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.021s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.408s  (  0.491s elapsed)

  %GC     time      69.1%  (73.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,681,440,521 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  30.9% of total user, 25.9% of total elapsed
```

`covariance'''`:

```
8.333349999886264e10
     336,108,336 bytes allocated in the heap
     202,943,312 bytes copied during GC
      47,493,864 bytes maximum residency (10 sample(s))
      13,578,520 bytes maximum slop
             115 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       633 colls,     0 par    0.053s   0.055s     0.0001s    0.0002s
  Gen  1        10 colls,     0 par    0.089s   0.131s     0.0131s    0.0472s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.095s  (  0.086s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.142s  (  0.186s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.011s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.240s  (  0.286s elapsed)

  %GC     time      59.2%  (65.1% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,522,631,228 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  40.8% of total user, 34.1% of total elapsed
```

As you can see, a lot of the allocation is dependent on the mean we go with. We get the biggest boost by using `mean''` with the strict pair constructor, even with the naive `zipWith` implementation.

I'm working on wiring up the implementations with [`weigh`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/weigh), so I may have some more data in a bit.

Beyond tuning the component functions, I don't know of a much more performant way of dealing with `covmat`, but the strict pair constructor at least should improve your space characteristics regardless of what else you do.

EDIT: `weigh` results

```
Case                                  Allocated    GCs
naive mean                          723,716,168  1,382
applicative mean                    723,714,736  1,382
optimized mean, naive zipWith       456,000,688    875
optimized mean, hand-tuned zipWith  336,000,672    642
```

Second EDIT:

I grabbed Gabriel's awesome `foldl` to see what sort of performance we can get without having to hand-tune mean with the explicit strict pair.

```
import qualified Control.Foldl as L

mean''' :: [Double] -> Double
mean''' = L.fold (liftA2 (/) L.sum L.genericLength)

covariance'''' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance'''' xs ys = mean''' (zipWith (*) xs ys) - mean''' xs * mean''' ys

covariance''''' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance''''' xs ys = let mx = mean''' xs
                            my = mean''' ys
                        in
                        mean''' (zipWith (\x y -> (x - mx) * (y - my)) xs ys)
```

Allocation results:

`covariance''''`:

```
8.333350000320508e10
     336,108,272 bytes allocated in the heap
     222,635,752 bytes copied during GC
      61,198,528 bytes maximum residency (10 sample(s))
      13,627,544 bytes maximum slop
             140 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       633 colls,     0 par    0.052s   0.054s     0.0001s    0.0003s
  Gen  1        10 colls,     0 par    0.105s   0.155s     0.0155s    0.0592s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.110s  (  0.099s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.156s  (  0.209s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.014s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.269s  (  0.323s elapsed)

  %GC     time      58.1%  (64.5% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,054,641,122 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  41.8% of total user, 34.9% of total elapsed
```

`covariance'''''`:

```
8.333349999886264e10
     336,108,232 bytes allocated in the heap
     202,942,400 bytes copied during GC
      47,493,816 bytes maximum residency (10 sample(s))
      13,578,568 bytes maximum slop
             115 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       633 colls,     0 par    0.057s   0.059s     0.0001s    0.0003s
  Gen  1        10 colls,     0 par    0.086s   0.126s     0.0126s    0.0426s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.096s  (  0.087s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.143s  (  0.184s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.011s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.241s  (  0.285s elapsed)

  %GC     time      59.2%  (64.7% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,504,449,342 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  40.8% of total user, 34.5% of total elapsed
```

And `weigh` results:

```
foldl mean                          336,000,568    642
foldl mean, tuned zipWith           336,000,568    642
```

In summary, it looks like the `foldl` implementation is your best bet. It's extremely clear about what it's doing, and pulls some really fancy tricks to stream inputs efficiently, meeting or exceeding the result of our hand-tuning. You could probably eke some extra juice out of all this using another data structure, but this is pretty good performance for the humble list. :D

Third edit:

I've never used Edward's `folds` before, so I may be doing something very stupid, but I also tried out an implementation using those.

```
import qualified Data.Fold as F

sumL :: Num a => F.L a a
sumL = F.L id (+) 0

lengthL :: Num b => F.L a b
lengthL = F.L id (const . (+1)) 0

mean'''' :: [Double] -> Double
mean'''' = flip F.run (liftA2 (/) sumL lengthL)

covariance'''''' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance'''''' xs ys = mean'''' (zipWith (*) xs ys) - mean'''' xs * mean'''' ys

covariance''''''' :: [Double] -> [Double] -> Double
covariance''''''' xs ys = let mx = mean'''' xs
                              my = mean'''' ys
                        in
                        mean'''' (zipWith (\x y -> (x - mx) * (y - my)) xs ys)
```

Allocation results:

`covariance''''''`:

```
8.333350000320508e10
     456,108,488 bytes allocated in the heap
     394,432,096 bytes copied during GC
      79,295,648 bytes maximum residency (15 sample(s))
      21,161,776 bytes maximum slop
             201 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       861 colls,     0 par    0.089s   0.092s     0.0001s    0.0003s
  Gen  1        15 colls,     0 par    0.198s   0.276s     0.0184s    0.0720s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.135s  (  0.119s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.287s  (  0.367s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.019s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.425s  (  0.506s elapsed)

  %GC     time      67.6%  (72.5% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,388,218,993 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  32.3% of total user, 27.1% of total elapsed
```

`covariance'''''''`:

```
8.333349999886264e10
     456,108,552 bytes allocated in the heap
     291,275,200 bytes copied during GC
      62,670,040 bytes maximum residency (11 sample(s))
      15,029,432 bytes maximum slop
             172 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                     Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
  Gen  0       862 colls,     0 par    0.068s   0.070s     0.0001s    0.0003s
  Gen  1        11 colls,     0 par    0.149s   0.210s     0.0191s    0.0570s

  INIT    time    0.000s  (  0.002s elapsed)
  MUT     time    0.118s  (  0.104s elapsed)
  GC      time    0.217s  (  0.280s elapsed)
  EXIT    time    0.001s  (  0.016s elapsed)
  Total   time    0.337s  (  0.403s elapsed)

  %GC     time      64.3%  (69.6% elapsed)

  Alloc rate    3,870,870,585 bytes per MUT second

  Productivity  35.7% of total user, 29.9% of total elapsed
```

And `weigh` results:

```
folds mean                          456,000,784    875
folds mean, tuned zipWith           456,000,888    871
```

Another EDIT: I also tried the `folds` option using `L'` rather than `L`, but the results were the same.

Comment: Inspired by this I tried testing my solution, and found that I got 1MB total memory in use on the same example, using [my own application of the foldl library](https://gist.github.com/user54038/44f0c28bd03a01b8c6fafc6ec6c5a29a). The key is to define a covariance Fold, which can be done in terms of the mean Fold (I used Gabriel's builtin L.mean rather than redefining it). Then you fold once with the covariance Fold, rather than using the mean Fold multiple times.

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic. Great solution.